# Rhythmic Metallic grinding noise from under hood

Tags: noise, vauxhall, grinding, metal

I have a 2012 Vauxhall Astra 1.6L Petrol, the query I have is the same as someone else’s but unfortunately they haven’t updated in 2 years so I assume they’re idle

There’s a grinding under the hood most noticeable when idle but increases when RPM does too

I was told it’s the AC compressor so got it changed, the noise did go away perfectly, but as I refilled the gas, I noticed the noise came back.

The previous compressor caused issues whereby even when ac was on, I’d need to accelerate more in order to pull off from gear 1, that has stopped as I’ve changed the compressor

Is there any other issue or would it be the compressor again (which was a second hand used part), if not what on earth could it be

I’ve got videos from online of [grinding noise under hood](https://youtube.com/shorts/r8-PVjQjWPE?feature=share) what it is as the sound is good

[grinding noise from inside](https://imgur.io/gallery/R2MCxvp)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: With a mechanically driver compressor running you'll typically need a bit more juice to pull away. And to climb hills, where the smart thing is to switch the AC off while making a long steep ascent.